# Is there a way to find all the synchronous methods used in a NodeJS project?

Tags: node.js

Is there a way to find *all* the synchronous methods used (called) in a NodeJS project ?

I mean, even inside some custom method that calls a function implemented in some npm module which in turns calls a core synchronous NodeJS method.

Comment: Can you define "synchronous"?  I mean, the whole project is going to be synchronous at some level.  Do you mean only methods that have the standard node callback signatures `func(errback, [data]){}`?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: by synchronous I mean code that at some point calls some native synchronous method (ie. readFileSync)